# Como botar um count dentro de uma box

Tags: html, mysql, css

eu queria colocar um contador de tempo ( ex: uma promoção de 10% por um determinado tempo) 
teria como fazer isso com mysql ?

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda de como começar a fazer isso?
( como colocar o count dentro dessa box )

no momento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo:

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <section id="promo">
<?php
                $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtohome");
                $consulta -> execute();

                $linhas = $consulta -> rowCount();

                foreach($consulta as $mostra):
            ?>
 <div class="card">
      <img class="skin"src="images/<?= $mostra['produto_img']?>" alt="Nome da Empresa: 
      <?= $mostra['produto_nome']?>" title="Nome da Empresa: <?= $mostra['produto_nome']?>">
      <div class="info">
        <p class="color-white text-center font-text-light-med font-weight-heavy bgcolor-black"><?= $mostra['produto_nome']?></p>
      </div>
      <p class="preccor">Por: R$ <?= number_format($mostra['produto_preco'], 2,',','.')?></p>
      <button class="bgcolor-red text-center btn"><a href="comprar.php?prod=<?= $mostra['produto_id']?>">Comprar</a></button>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</section>
       </div>
```

css:

```
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 180px;;
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card:hover {
box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
.skin {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}
.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
img.skin{height: 130px;width: 180px;}
p.preccor{margin-top: 30px;}
.card .info {margin-top: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FF4141;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
```

estava querendo adicionar um contador desse tipo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu queria saber se tem como fazer isso com mysql determinando o tempo por lá e estou com dificuldade para adicionar dentro da div .

Comment: o banco de dados só guarda informações, não serve pra contar tempo, o que aparece na página tem de ser feito com html/javascript nesse caso. O que você poderia fazer é guardar a data final, pegar essa data e fazer o contador na página, ai não depende mais nada do banco. Agora se estiver com dificuldade de pagar uma informação do banco e colocar na tela, a dúvida é um pouco diferente, não é exatamente o contador em si, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Não tenho dificuldade com pegar a informação do banco de dados, meu problema é colocar esse contador dentro dessa box ( html / css) essa parte do mysql e php eu consigo fazer.